Is it accepted practice to drill holes in metal studs
I am getting a house built in Australia where I have opted for metal framing (to mitigate termite attacks).  I have no experience in metal framing.
As much as I can think ahead, I am getting the builder to add timber dwangs where I may want to fasten things in the future.  But there will be unforeseen requirements, once the house is finished.
Is it accepted practice to drill into the metal framing (studs) at a later stage to fasten things?
As mentioned, I am used to timber studs, so I know how much I can carve out of it.  But I have no idea about the metal framing.  To me, the metal frame sounds flimsy (in comparison).  Typical things that may need fastening

Bathroom fan heaters
TVs
Shelves


I never heard "dwangs" before; it is apparently Scotland/NZ English. In the US it would be called "blocking".

@Ecnerwal, good point.  However there is not much weight (turning moment) involved.

@Theodore, see also "noggin". #TIL :D

How do you think they fasten metal studs to metal top and bottom plates?

You could use TREX or manufactured plastic wood and not have termite problems with your "dwangs".

It is, and it's done often, such as for drywall, bath fixtures, etc. Small holes for fasteners generally aren't a concern.
If you want to cut out more material, though, consult the tech literature provided by the manufacturer.

I have in many instances, fastened items to metal studs
: flat screen TV's, shelves, etc. When doing so, I've used toggle bolts or molly bolts. You need to drill in the middle of the stud. You can punch a few very small holes in the wall to find where the stud starts and where it ends and then determine the middle of it. Some stud finders might work too. Then put the toggle or molly through your item and through the drywall and metal stud. The "wings" will expand with no problem and then tighten. Stay away from using plastic anchors because the metal will just shear the anchors in half.

And where toggle bolts on only drywall are of limited use, toggle bolts through drywall + metal studs are very strong.

I've also done this, but I have no idea whether a 3/8" or 1/2" hole in the stud flange voids any warranty. I'm hesitant to recommend it in a new home situation. Keep in mind that a steel stud flange isn't 1-1/2" wide. It's more like 1-1/4".

In France we use mostly metal studs.
If you want to fasten something into a stud, you can simply use a drywall screw, they are designed to make their own hole into metal studs. If what you want to fasten is thick, just use a longer drywall screw.
There is no issue when making some holes in the studs, they're here to screw drywall into after all. You'd only get problems with large holes, say if you remove the whole side of the stud then sure it will lose most of its strength, but a fastener hole is no problem.
This is much stronger than fastening into drywall. However, the stud wall is very thin, and it holds the screw at only one point.
Thus it is strong versus pulling forces, but weak against forces parallel to the wall. The latter will attempt to bend the screw down. With wood studs, the screw is buried an inch into wood so it has good leverage to resist, but in steel studs this is not the case: the only thing resisting downward forces is the drywall reacting against the side of the screw, and drywall crushes easily.
OK. Since I did some drywall today, I took some pics to explain:

Basically, don't use a long drywall screw as clothes hanger. If it is compressing whatever it is fastening against the drywall and relying on friction to prevent it from sliding, then it's fine. But without that, it has very little strength in the direction parallel to the wall.

The usual solution is either friction, or a thicker fastener, so its side has more drywall to rest on when a downward force is applied. For example, Mollies.
For very heavy loads like a TV, you can definitely drill into the stud and use a Molly. If you make a suspended drywall ceiling using metal studs, this is the standard way to hang heavy lights.
Here's a French Molly document. Sorry I don't have an English version, but it should be pretty easy to understand.

The label on the box of Mollies says "30kg". But that's the rating for a force parallel to the wall! They are much weaker against pulling.
The important thing is on the bottom left: a Molly in drywall is only rated for 3kg pulling force, but if it is in a metal stud, it is 5x stronger.
